Pipenv Won't Lock Library
I am trying to create a Pipfile.lock in my repo so I can run a Veracode scan.  The version I use is: 2024.0.0 and I also have the most recent version of pip.  I ran these commands:
pipenv install -r /path/to/requirements.txt
and
pipenv install --pre -r /path/to-requirements.txt
both say that it refuses to lock because there are "No matching distribution found for [library]."  This is one of the libraries I am trying to use.  I tried doing a pipenv install of the [library] and it doesn't find that either.  I don't know how to proceed if Pipenv doesn't recognize a library that I need in my code.  Any thoughts?

A few things that might help us :

which version of python are you running ?
could you share the content of requirements.txt ?

Note that a pipenv install genai-sdk doesn't work, it is not hosted on pypi. Is it a package from a private repository ?
A few elements that could help you also in the use of Pipenv :
Try first to see if the skip-lock mecanism is working also :
pipenv install --skip-lock -r path/to/requirements.txt

If it's not working, you might have an error into your requirements file.
Either, if it's working, you might have a problem during the locking mecanism.
Hence by doing a more verbose install command, we can get further information :
pipenv install -vv -r path/to/requirements.txt


Am running Python 3.12.  Managed to get it to lock last night, by removing one of the requirements, but now I am getting a new error.  This is the error:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ERROR: Failed building wheel for chroma-hnswlib
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: Could not build wheels for cchardet, chroma-hnswlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
ERROR: Couldn't install package: {}
 Package installation failed...


I think I am just lost on how exactly to get pipenv installed correctly.  Let me tell you what I tried.  First, I am using PyCharm.  Pycharm asks if you want it to create a venv when you create the project.  The first thing I tried is to opt for that and THEN from the terminal inside the project, I ran pip install pipenv.  That gives you what you see above.  Second, I tried just creating a new project in PyCharm with the code but WITHOUT a .venv.  The issue there is that without a .venv I don't have pip.  So maybe I am just setting the project up wrong?  The JetBrains docs aren't helpful.

PyCharm also gives you the option of creating a project with a pipenv file, but it asks for the path to the pipenv.exe file....  But i don't have a pipenv.exe file, and I cannot seem to see where I can get it.  I looked at the pipenv docs, but they all talk about installing using pip.

Installing pipenv is done thought pip or better option with pipx. So your installation is ok, given you are using a virtual environement provided by PyCharm.
The earlier error related to a build problem. Have a look to ensure you have a build dependencies installed to build and recompile wheels.
You can achieve this by doing a pipenv install -vvv

This didn't solve the problem but it gave me an error that lead me to the solution.  One of the libraries required Microsoft Build Tools be installed and so I see there is a separate question about this on Stack Overflow and that is what I did.  I installed the cpp build tools.
